# Change parse password reset email text

Tags: email, parse-platform, password-recovery

I am hosting parse-server on my own elastik beanstalk instance and want toi change the email that is sent out to user when they request a password reset.

I know it can be changed from the dashboard when hsoting on parse, but I do not have the option to do so now its hosted on my own instance. I cant find where I would be able to change this

Comment: have you used parse-server or parse-server-example?

Comment: Hi, I am using the parse-server-example and need to change the email text. Did you find any way to change the text? I know that it can be changed in the UserController.js (in parse-server), but do not know how to make that change in parse-server-example - https://github.com/ParsePlatform/parse-server-example